# Passing a data.frame from R to Ruby using RinRuby

Tags: ruby, r

I'm using the RinRuby gem to work with R in Ruby. The problem is, that you can only pass vectors containing characters or numerics from R to Ruby with RinRuby, but I want to pass a data.frame.

My first idea was to convert the data.frame into a JSON object, which I could pass as a string from R to Ruby and then convert it to a Hash. But this solution seems to be quite complicated.

Does anyone has a better idea?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether "use Rserve-Ruby-client instead of RinRuby" counts as a better idea - perhaps you have a good reason for using RinRuby. However, the [Rserve client](https://github.com/clbustos/Rserve-Ruby-client) can be used to convert data frames to Ruby arrays:

```
require 'rserve'
con = Rserve::Connection.new
df1 = con.eval("data.frame(a = c(1:10), b = c(11:20))")
df1 = df1.to_ruby
#<Array:69904955249600 [a=12345678910, b=11121314151617181920]>
df1['a']
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dump or dput functions to return ASCII representations of R objects.

```
> dump('dat', file="")
dat <-
structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c(" pilot01", 
" pilot02"), class = "factor"), val2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("t1", "t3"), class = "factor"), val1 = c(429.226015, 
693.795607, 262.798468, 325.854107), val1time = structure(c(29229.226015, 
29493.795607, 29062.798468, 29125.854107), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), .Names = c("group", "val2", "val1", "val1time"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(dat)
structure(list(group = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c(" pilot01", 
" pilot02"), class = "factor"), val2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("t1", "t3"), class = "factor"), val1 = c(429.226015, 
693.795607, 262.798468, 325.854107), val1time = structure(c(29229.226015, 
29493.795607, 29062.798468, 29125.854107), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"))), .Names = c("group", "val2", "val1", "val1time"), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Dataframes in R are just lists with rownames and column names. Does Ruby have data-types for date-time vectors and for lists? If so, it should be fairly straightforward to pull apart the list structure. The alternative would be to use `lapply` (in the R environment) to column-wise perform RinRuby operations that you would reassemble in Ruby.